# Detect when UnityXR laser is pointing to object

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, unity-xr

I would like know how using unity XRPackage I can detect when the XRRAyInteractor is poiting to a specific 3D object. Can anyone demonstrate that to me?